jQuery Click Event not working on mobile?
I've tried numerous other stackoverflow posts, but I can't get my click event to work on mobile at all. It works great on desktop. Here's my code, and here's a link to my website: nexusdevcon.com (the code is applied to the "Learn More" buttons in the Services section)
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('.serviceToggle').on('click', function(){
        //do stuff
  });
});


You should try to solve this error first : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Huh, well that's interesting.. that error only appears when I'm logged out of wordpress. I don't get it when I'm logged in. Guess that is the issue

Are you enqueuing jquery?
function enqueue_custom_script(){
wp_enqueue_script('your-script-handle', 'path-to-your-script', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "enqueue_custom_script");
